# Python multiprocessing wating for k tasks to finish before executing a second task

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I would like to process a list `lst` of `n` elements divided into chunks of length `k` in the following way:

1. Having a pool of `p` multiprocessing workers
2. use the pool to process `task1` on each of the elements in `lst`.
3. once all elements of a chunk are processed by `task1`, pass its elements to `task2` (also using the pool of processes)
4. keep processing the remaining elements in `lst` simultaneously while executing `task2` on the finished chunks.

I first tried to use two pools, one inside another. But python multiprocessing won't allow this. How can I achieve the same result in another way?

Comment: Why not call `task2` from inside `task1` once it's finished processing the elements? You would still be using multiple workers. Also, does the order of the results need to be preserved?

Comment: Hi, because `task2` works on the results of multiple `task1`s and has to wait for k of those to start. The order of the results should be preserved, however it that makes things complicated then I can give up that requirement.

Comment: Is the work you do inside task1 and task2 cpu-heavy?

Comment: Yes, however task2 heavier. why?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Charchit said, call task2 from task1 is the best way.
Even so you still want to implement this method, you can refer to the following:

```
# Version: v3.0
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, Value, Lock, Process, Manager
from functools import partial


def f(q, x):
    r = x * x
    # get lock and count finish
    l.acquire()
    finish_cnt.value += 1
    # use share
    q.put(r)
    l.release()

    print(f"t1: {x}")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return r


def f2(q, x):
    r = x + x
    l.acquire()
    finish2_cnt.value += 1
    l.release()
    print(f"t2: {x}")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return r


def worker1(c, cnt, q):
    with Pool(c) as p:
        rlt = p.map(partial(f, q), [i for i in range(cnt)])
    print(f"{q.empty()}rlt1: ", len(rlt), rlt)
    return rlt


def worker2(c, cnt, q):
    rlt = []
    with Pool(c) as p:
        task2_cache = []
        while True:
            # get task2 input list from queue
            for i in range(c):
                l.acquire()
                if not task_queue.empty():
                    task2_cache.append(task_queue.get())
                l.release()
            if len(task2_cache) == core_num:
                print(f"{finish2_cnt.value}--->>>>", task2_cache)
                rlt.extend(p.map(partial(f2, q), task2_cache))
                task2_cache.clear()
                print("---<<<<", task2_cache)
            # break after task1 done
            if cnt == finish_cnt.value:
                rlt.extend(p.map(partial(f2, q), task2_cache))
            if cnt == finish2_cnt.value:
                break
    print("rlt2: ", len(rlt), rlt)
    return rlt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task_cnt = 100
    core_num = 8

    l = Lock()
    m = Manager()
    task_queue = m.Queue()
    finish_cnt = m.Value("i", 0)
    finish2_cnt = m.Value("i", 0)

    p1 = Process(target=worker1, args=(core_num, task_cnt, task_queue,))
    p2 = Process(target=worker2, args=(core_num, task_cnt, task_queue,))

    p2.start()
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print("finish all")
    print(finish_cnt.value, finish2_cnt.value)
```

Comment: That would start mapping `f2` only after finishing mapping `f`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can try to debug it.

Comment: Ok thanks. but I'm looking for a solution that would start running `task2` before finishing all `task1`s, not sequentially. Thanks

Comment: I updated my code, this version may suit your needs. t2 will consume the queue output by t1. @A.Maman

Comment: Hi, thanks! But from the code and also testing by running it I noticed that here also `task2` starts only after `task1` finishes. The goal is to have them run simultaneously and not sequentially. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: This is a demo I wrote temporarily, please forgive my negligence.You try again this version should work, also, my best practice is to create a producer and a consumer through Pope, and communicate between them consume tasks through pipes.@A.Maman

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the chunks themselves to a sort of intermediatory worker. Let this worker iterate over these chunks and pass them to `task1`. After they have processed them, this worker will then compile the values returned and pass them to `task2`. Sample:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random


def task1(element):
    return element


def task2(chunk):
    return 'return value'


def worker(element_chunk):
    processed_element = []
    for element in element_chunk:
        processed_element.append(task1(element))

    return task2(processed_element)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 25
    k = 5
    p = 8

    # Sample lst
    lst = random.sample(range(100), n)

    # Separate lst into chunks of size k
    element_chunks = []
    for i in range(n // k):
        element_chunks.append(lst[k * i: k * i + k])

    print(element_chunks)

    pool = Pool(p)
    result_chunks = pool.map(worker, element_chunks)

    print(result_chunks)
```

Provided that `p` is optimal, doing it this way would also be faster (if only marginally) if the elements in `lst` are repeating, or can be optimized if pickled in chunks rather than separately, in general.

**Output**

```
[[44, 0, 90, 35, 10], [28, 16, 39, 72, 25], [51, 95, 80, 52, 77], [50, 64, 73, 59, 78], [21, 41, 14, 83, 58]]
['return value', 'return value', 'return value', 'return value', 'return value']
```

**Update**

A better version of the code below would be to only create a single pool of the maximum optimal size, and use that for starting both task1 and task2. Creating two pools is rarely a good idea. Regardless, the below code starts `task1` in `p` processes (without using the previous indirect worker) and continuously checks whether at least one batch of size `k` has been completed. If one has, it spawns a new process to complete `task2` on it:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random
import time


def task1(element):
    random.sample(range(100000000, 900000000), 1000000)
    return element


def task2(chunk, index):
    print(f'Number {index} task2 completed')
    random.sample(range(100000000, 900000000), 1000000)
    return 'return value'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 20
    k = 5
    p = 8

    # Sample lst
    lst = random.sample(range(100), n)

    t = time.time()
    pool1 = Pool(p)
    pool2 = Pool(p)

    # Create tasks for each task1 without waiting for them to complete
    tasks = []
    for element in lst:
        tasks.append(pool1.apply_async(task1, (element,)))

    # Check if any of the task1 have been completed, and if they have start a task2 on the result in a separate process
    task2_results = []
    task1_results = []

    task1_counter = 0
    task2_counter = 0
    while len(tasks) > 0:
        for index, task in enumerate(tasks):
            if task.ready():
                task1_counter += 1
                print(f"{task1_counter} task1 finished")
                task1_results.append(task.get())
                tasks[index] = None

            if len(task1_results) == k:
                task2_counter += 1
                print(f"{task2_counter} task2 starting")
                task2_results.append(pool2.apply_async(task2, (task1_results[0:k], task2_counter)))
                task1_results = []

        tasks = [task for task in tasks if task is not None]

    # Wait for all task2 to complete
    for index, result in enumerate(task2_results):
        task2_results[index] = result.get()

    print(f"finished in {time.time() - t}")
    print(task2_results)
```

Again, if the work is cpu-bound, and the total `p` is optimal, then I would be *really* surprised if this offers any improvements in speed over creating a single pool.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But if I get it right, this way I do not utilize parallelism while processing `task1` on the `k` elements in each chunk. I would like to process the `k` elements in (say) `k` processes and pass the result to another process that performs `task2` on those.

Comment: @A.Maman You cannot just keep spawning processes as you see fit and expect it to have better efficiency. You mentioned that your tasks are cpu-bound, that means that your code will be the most performant if the number of processes concurrently running are equal to the number of cores your device has. Any more and you will actually end up slowing it down. Infact, when you use a pool, it automatically spawns the optimal number of processes for you, divides the total tasks and sends them to each process **serially**. It's a faulty assumption to believe that all tasks are executed concurrently.

Comment: The `worker` in the code above actually is a good pseudocode for how pools work in general. The parallelism comes from the fact that there are 8 (most devices today have 8 cores) of these running, **and not from the fact that the actual tasks in each worker are executed parallel to each other** (again that would actually end up slowing the tasks down, the cpu can only do so many things at once).

Comment: Hi, @Charchit. First, thanks for the input. I do plan to have a constant number of processes (roughly the number of cpus), I also do understand that a pool of much more will end up slowing the program down. My intent is not to process *all* the elements in `lst` concurrently but to have `p` workers that will process them. That is, say we had only `task1` with 8 cpu cores, I would like to have 8 workers working on all `lst` elements and reducing the time it takes to calculate `task1` by roughly 8x. The addition is by triggering say one of the 8 workers on `task2` each time `k` elements of `lst`

Comment: ... finish being processed. I am familiar with how multiprocessing pool works, but i'm working on a machine with 72 cores and when experimenting the two tasks (1 & 2) separately on this machine using multiprocessing had accelerated the computation significantly. That's why I want to utilize it for both. However, when tried to simply call one task inside another an error raised telling that it's not possible to create a pool inside a pool, that's why i'm asking if there's another way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, assuming an 8 core device, if you spawn 8 processes for `task1`, and 8 processes for `task2`, you are still spawning more processes (double, actually) than ideal when doing cpu-bound work. Starting a pool from inside a worker will not make your code more performant (even if it was possible). I *really* doubt whether trying to spawn 16 processes that do cpu-bound work (8 for `task1` and 8 for `task2`), even though they run concurrently, will produce better results than spawning 8 processes that do a batch of `task1` and immediately *after* start on  `task2`. But feel free to experiment.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. The point is not about the number of cpus. I don't plan to run 16 processes on a machine that only has 8 cores. Here I could use say 4 for `task1`, 4 for `task2`, or even two for each. (Actually, on my machine, I have 72 cores, so I can utilize even more, but the question is not about this). The question concerns *implementing* a program that uses some workers for one task and has other workers process another task and how to make them work *simultaneously*. Once I had this, I could experiment with the optimal allocation of cores for each task. Thanks!

Comment: @A.Maman check the edit for how you can do that. Keep in mind if you decide to follow this method, the order of results will not be preserved

Comment: @A.Maman I had forgotten to mention that in an older edit, the code was passing whole, size `k` chunks to an indirect worker which produced `task1` on it serially. This would not be ideal in case the number of `k` chunks was less than the processes in the pool itself. So in the latest edit, I had altered the code so that `pool1` runs task1 parallelly on all its processes, and as soon as a size `k` chunk is processed, it passes it to `pool2` to do `task2` on it simultaneously. I forgot to ping you after I made that edit, so if its still relevant, then use this code if it suits your case better.